# PID Control of UUV Simulator

Tags: ros, pid, gazebo-simulator

I installed the [uuv_simulator](https://github.com/uuvsimulator/uuv_simulator) and I was successful on simulating a BlueROV2. The simulator has some examples and implementations of PID controllers but I am not able to take advantage of them.

My goal is to take full control of the bluerov in terms of PID. I tried looking into the code of the simulator and rostopics/nodes but it was not pleasant due to the nested things that were executed with just one launch file.

I came across [this presentation](https://youtu.be/vaf6vMgOWKY?t=370) where he mentioned that it is possible to make a trajectory controller or through a service called `GoTo`.
For the first I have no clue since I'm new to the world of the robotics in general but for the second I find the service call and tried to make a script which would publish messages (Waypoints) but it didn't actually work.

So, if anyone has any idea on how to take control of the robot please let me know.

Thanks in advance.